# How to display 2 cells in one row in UICollectionView in Swift?

Tags: swift, uicollectionview

I want to display 2 items in each row, and I am using this arithmetics

```
    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: 
    UICollectionViewLayout, sizeForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGSize 
      {
        let width = (collectionView.frame.width - 2) / 3
        return CGSize(width: width, height: width)
     }
```

to get this [image: output] but i am not getting only 2 cells in a row between them not too much padding.

Please can you help me with this one.

and i am creating the layout like this one

```
        if let layout = collectionView.collectionViewLayout as? UICollectionViewFlowLayout {
        layout.sectionInset = .init(top: padding * 2, left: padding, bottom: padding, right: padding)
        layout.minimumInteritemSpacing = 1
        layout.minimumLineSpacing = 15
    }
```

Comment: How much peddling have you set for section insets?

Comment: let width = ((collectionView.frame.width - (padding * 2)) -  2) / 2

Answer (score 1):

It should be `minimumLineSpacing`, not `minimumInteritemSpacing` or cell space. Because your collectionView's scroll direction is horizontal.

If it is vertical then you need to set cell space or inter item space for horizontal space between cells and line spacing for vertical space between cells.

Try reducing the `minimumLineSpacing`.

```
layout.minimumLineSpacing = 15 // Keep whatever fits for you
```

or

```
  func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, minimumLineSpacingForSectionAt section: Int) -> CGFloat {
    return 15 // Keep whatever fits for you
  }
```